# jQuery AJAX call to sevlet not working in anchor tag

Tags: jsp, jquery, servlets

I am new to jQuery and Servlets. Working on a school project and now I am stuck at this problem.

I have a navigation bar on left with anchor tags like this in my proj3.html file.

```
  <ul class="nav nav-list">

          <li class="nav-header">Labels</li>
          <li><a href="" class="labels">Sony</a></li>
          <li><a href="" class="labels">Spinnin</a></li>
          <li><a href="" class="labels">BMG</a></li>
          <li><a href="" class="labels">Ultra</a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="labels">Universal</a></li>

          <li class="nav-header">Genere</li>
          <li><a href="" class="genere">Rock</a></li>
          <li><a href="" class="genere">Alternative Rock</a></li>
          <li><a href="" class="genere">Pop</a></li>
          <li><a href="" class="genere">EDM</a></li>
          <li><a href="" class="genere">Hip-Hop</a></li>
       </ul>
```

Inside Javascript i have this

```
 $('a.labels').on('click',function(e){

        var url = "http://example.edu/servlet/SampleQuery";       
            $.get(url);
        e.preventDefault();
    }

}
```

Inside my servlet SampleQuery.java I read from DB and forward to a JSP like this

```
       RequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;
       dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/DisplayVendor.jsp"); 
   dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

When I click on any of the anchor tags `$.get` is hit, but my JSP page is not getting displayed. Weird thing is if I check the firebug for network traffic I see my AJAX call going through and I can even see DisplayVendor.jsp page in response. But its not getting displayed.

Can someone please point out if I am making any mistake.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `$.get(url)`, but don't do anything with the response. Change it to

```
$.get(url, function(data) {
    alert('here is the response data : ' + data);
});
```

to show what you received.

To update the contents of the div with id "dynamicallyLoadedDiv" with the HTML returned by the AJAX call, for example, use

```
$.get(url, function(data) {
    $('#dynamicallyLoadedDiv').html(data);
});
```

or simply

```
$('#dynamicallyLoadedDiv').load(url);
```

Read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for more information.

Note that if your goal is to replace the whole page content, I don't really seee the point of making an AJAX request. Use a simple hyperlink in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think i will use a simple hyperlink instead. But just out of curiosity Why doesn't forwarding to a JSP from servlet work with AJAX? and the reason why I used $.get(url) without success function is, I was under the assumption that I wont get response back since I was forwarding to new JSP page.

Comment: You don't understand what forwarding is. It happens completely at server side. The servlet is called with a request and response as argument. It executes its logic, and then forwards to a JSP. This consists in saying: I have done my part of the job, now the JSP should do its part (with the same request and the same response). So it's exactly as if the servlet called doGet() of another servlet at the end of its own doGet() method. Then, the JSP generates HTML code dynamically and sends it to the response. Then your JavaScript receives the response, and is supposed to do something with it.